# В какой области памяти хранятся переменные в Java

Tags: java, стек, heap

В Java примитивы и ссылки на объекты хранятся в стэке, а объекты в куче.
Предположим есть объект `user` класса `User`, у которого имеются поля `int age` и `String name`. На вершину стэка ложиться ссылка на `user`, сам объект `user` хранится в куче. А где будет храниться его поле `age` и ссылка на `name`?

Так же в стэке, сверху над ссылкой на сам `user`? В том смысле, что когда завершится функция, которая создавала `user` - то указатель стэка должен сместиться вниз, и все эти переменные - ссылка на `user`, примитив `int age` и ссылка на `name` должны исчезнуть из памяти.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> В Java примитивы и ссылки на объекты хранятся в стэке, а объекты в
>   куче.

Это не так. Ссылки и примитивы тоже могут храниться в куче, а [объекты могут храниться в стеке](https://habr.com/ru/company/jugru/blog/322348/).

Важно понимать разницу между переменной и полем.

```
class User {
    private int age = 42;
    private String name = "John Doe";

    public void someMethod() {
        int someVar = 2;
        User user = new User();
    }
}
```

`age` - это поле. Оно имеет примитивный тип, но храниться будет там же, где и объект - в куче. Так же и поле ссылочного типа `name`.

`someVar` и `user` - это переменные и они хранятся в стеке. В первой хранится значение 2, во втором ссылка на объект класса `User`.

> В том смысле, что когда завершится функция, которая создавала user -
>   то указатель стэка должен сместиться вниз, и все эти переменные -
>   ссылка на user, примитив int age и ссылка на name должны исчезнуть из
>   памяти.

При завершении метода `someMethod` кадр стека будет уничтожен и вместе с ним перестанут существовать переменные `someVar` и `user`. Но сам объект `user` останется в куче до следующего вызова сборщика мусора. Сборщик мусора при запуске проверит все существующие кадры стека, не найдёт в них ссылки на объект `user` и только тогда удалит его.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю. в main() создаю объект user - ссылка на него хранится в стэке, сам объект, вместе с полями age и name - в куче, несмотря на то, что age является примитивом. Вызываю метод user.someMethod() - примитив someVar и ссылка на внутренний объект user (назовем его innerUser) опять создаются в стэке, а сам объект innerUser - в куче. Когда метод someMethod() завершился, то кадр стэка вместе с локальными переменными удаляется.

Comment: @ТимурБаймагамбетов да, всё верно.

Answer (score 2):

@Sergey Gornostaev [объекты могут храниться в стеке](https://habr.com/ru/company/jugru/blog/322348/)

Не вводите, пожалуйста, людей в заблуждение. В стеке хранятся ссылки на объекты, а не сами объекты. В статье говорится об оптимизациях, связанных с созданием объектов в куче. То есть если объект больше нигде не используется кроме метода, в котором он создан, то и создавать его не нужно. Это снижает затраты на работу GC.

Comment: вероятно, стоит уточнить, кому именно адресовано пожелаение не вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin добавил, спасибо. К сожалению, не могу оставлять комментарии под чужими ответами

Comment: Что, по-вашему, происходит при вызове `SomeObject obj = new SomeObject()`, если escape-анализ показал, что obj пределы метода не покидает? Объект obj не создаётся? А что тогда находится в obj с позиции прикладного кода?

Comment: поищите информацию об scalar remplacement

Comment: https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/18-scalar-replacement/