# Java scanner heap stack

Tags: java, стек, scanner, heap

Как написать в языке [java](/questions/tagged/java) код так, чтобы текст введенный из `scanner` попал в `stack`, а не в `heap`?

Comment: Это не возможно. Любые неконстантные тексты в Java хранятся в куче. Но думаю вы неправильно задали вопрос. Какую задачу вы хотите решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы текст, введённый при помощи сканера, попал в стек, а не в кучу, он должен быть представлен с помощью *отдельных* примитивов типа `char` ***в виде локальных переменных или аргументов методов***.  Другое дело, считать ли такой набор переменных текстом.

Ни строки `String`, ни массивы символов/целочисленных кодовых точек в стек не попадут, так как являются объектами.

Также "примитивные" `char`-ы попадут в кучу, [если они будут объявлены в качестве полей объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/980463/386633) или [статических полей](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8388036/13279831).

Однако сканер не обеспечивает посимвольного чтения -- в нём нет метода `public char nextChar()` подобного `nextInt / nextShort / nextByte`, а доступный метод `Scanner::next` всё равно будет возвращать строку.

Теоретически можно "сымитировать" посимвольный ввод, использовав `String::charAt`, для результата чтения, содержащего ровно 1 символ (не совпадающий с разделителями), создав [сканер с разделителем вида `"(?<=.)"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13370098/13279831).

Получится что-то вроде:

```java
private static char heapChar = '*'; // примитив в куче, игнорируем

public static void main(String ... args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("(?<=.)");
    char c0 = sc.next().charAt(0);
    char c1 = sc.next().charAt(0);
    char c2 = sc.next().charAt(0);
    char c3 = sc.next().charAt(0);
    char c4 = sc.next().charAt(0);
    // ...
    char cN = sc.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.print(c0);
    System.out.print(c1);
    System.out.print(c2);
    System.out.print(c3);
    System.out.print(c4);
    System.out.print(cN);
}
```

Для ввода:

```
ab cdef
```

результат будет такой (прочитано 6 символов из 7 введённых, включая пробел, по количеству переменных):

```
ab cde
```

т.е. формально будет заполнено 6 `char`-ов, которые будут недолго жить в стеке, пока не завершится текущий метод.

Для передачи "текста", полученного данным образом, придётся писать методы с соответствующим **точным** числом параметров типа `char`, чтобы сохранить этот "текст" в стеке.

```java
static void foo(char c0, char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4) {
}
```